# Icon (with svg) definition via symbolizer object

Tags: json

I would like to define the style in symbolizer-syntax (json). How can I set the icon-src style-property analogue to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/style-expressions.html?

The following seems not to work (only the stroke* works):

```
{
    "stroke-color": "darkgray",
    "stroke-width": 6,
    "icon-src" : "Logo.svg",
    "icon-size" : 50,
    "icon-color" : "pink"
}
```

I was expecting the Logo displayed when I create a new point-feature.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.